# Re-using UI in WPF from a Resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a several tabs on UI where on each tab I need the below:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <Button Content="&lt;" Command="{Binding MoveToPreviousCommand}" />
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name}" />
     <Button Content="&gt;" Command="{Binding MoveToNextCommand}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Is there a way to avoid replicating this code in XAML for each tab by specifying the above for example in the Resources only once and pointing into that resource under each tab?

Answer (score 3):

**Using ContentControl**

```
 <Window.Resources>       
    <StackPanel x:Key="Content" x:Shared="False" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="&lt;" Command="{Binding MoveToPreviousCommand}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name}" />
        <Button Content="&gt;" Command="{Binding MoveToNextCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="template1">
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="&lt;" Command="{Binding MoveToPreviousCommand}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name}" />
            <Button Content="&gt;" Command="{Binding MoveToNextCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Content}"></ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Name="contCtrl" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource template1}" Content="This is the content of the content control."/>
</StackPanel>
```

**using  usercontrol**

[image]

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
 <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="&lt;" Command="{Binding MoveToPreviousCommand}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name}" />
        <Button Content="&gt;" Command="{Binding MoveToNextCommand}" />
</StackPanel>
```

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">

<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I use the UserControl typically for this. +1

Comment: Using ContentControl: when StackPanel set directly in the Resources, it shows content only on one tab (whathever is defined last in XAML). On other tabs the ContentControl is not showing anything.

Comment: Using ContentControl: when DataTemplate is used instead I will get the desired behaviour after the bindings are made correctly: Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.MoveToPreviousCommand}"

Comment: @user2143213 you can use X:shared=false for this.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778%28v=vs.110%29.aspx