# How can I reuse XAML tags in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was wondering whether it was possible to instead of me copying pieces of code in XAML, to define something that I could link to. In more concrete terms, what I have is:

```
<Grid>

 // Definitions

 <Label Content="Name:" />
 <Label Content="Age:" Grid.Column="1"/>
 ...
 <Grid>
```

and now I would like to have something like `<Content_in_grid=nice_labels>` and it should simply copy these labels.

Notice: I do not want the grid, because these are some labels that I would like to bind with different properties.

PS: maybe a different perspective, imagine I would like to create a file properties comparison program with WPF. So you can imagine that I have to copy all those labels such as Filename, Date etc. static labels again, but for maintainability, if I would like to change Filename to File then I would have to search and replace instead of editing it in one place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this kind of job is exactly the purpose of existence of a `UserControl`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698833/re-using-ui-in-wpf-from-a-resource/24699350#24699350

Answer (score 6):

Add it in the resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyGrid">
        <Grid>
            <Label Content="Name:" />
            <Label Content="Age:" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then use it where you want:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyGrid}" />
    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyGrid}" />
    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyGrid}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I think this wont work because an element can only be at one place at one time... And a resource is only instantiated once...

Comment: But I don't want to have the "grid" tag, only the label tags. So: `<Wraptag x:key><label... /><label... /></Wraptag>`, because I have the grid already, if I did this, wouldn't I get a grid in a grid?

Comment: I don't see any problem why you could not have a grid inside a grid

Comment: No, I just don't want to do that, because:

    <Grid>
    ...
    <label content="Static stuff" />
    ...
    <label content="{Binding ...}" />
    </Grid>

and I would like to copy only those static labels, because in a different grid I am also using the same static labels.

Comment: @Snowflake you can create a usercontrol with these two labels, and then just add a namespace for it and you can use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Flat Eric is almost correct.

I added `x:Shared="False"` though, because otherwise the Resource could only be used once and would only be visible in the last ContentPresenter. (It is visible in all ContentPresenters in the VisualStudio, but not in the final application).

PS: I saw that Flat Eric edited his answer, so that x:Shared is not necessary anymore. Anyway, the original answer, should be like this:

```
    <Grid x:Key="MyGrid" x:Shared="False" >
        <Label Content="Name:"/>
        <Label Content="Age:" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is templating the content based on a collection of items (you mentioned a file properties comparison tool, so I am guessing it could be a list of file properties).

You would in reality not add the `Labels` over and over again to a `Grid`, but would let the `Binding` system do it for you using (in your case) a `HeaderedItemsControl` such as a `DataGrid`.

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FileProperties}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PropertyName}" Header="Name:"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PropertyValue}" Header="Age:"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**NB**: `FileProperties` used in the `ItemsSource` would normally be an `ObservableCollection<T>` of a type that has `PropertyName` and `PropertyValue` properties.

You could achieve a similar effect using an `ItemsControl` and some static XAML for the header, but this is much neater overall.